ODBC Driver Error: File Not Found When Running Python Script in Docker Container
I'm running a Python script (sharepoint_to_json.py) inside a Docker container that connects to a SQL Server database using the ODBC driver. My goal is to convert data from an Excel (.xlsx) file into JSON format within my server, using the sharepoint_to_json.py script. This process should run inside the Docker container after establishing a connection to a SQL Server database.
I have already installed the msodbcsql17 driver in the container, and my connection to the database works when running other scripts. However, when I try to run the sharepoint_to_json.py script, I encounter the following error:
Ocorreu um erro ao processar o arquivo Excel: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
Here's the relevant part of my Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    apt-transport-https \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    python3-distutils \
    build-essential \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Upgrade pip, setuptools, wheel to ensure the latest versions
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

# Copy the requirements.txt file
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the project files
COPY . /app/

# Expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000

# Set environment variable to indicate that Django is running in the container
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Default command
CMD ["sh", "-c", "python wait_for_db.py && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python test_connection.py && python sharepoint_to_json.py && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"]

I verified that the msodbcsql17 driver is installed correctly in the container.
I checked the path /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/, but the file libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1 does not seem to exist.
I ensured that my odbcinst.ini is properly configured.
My Questions:
Why does the driver seem to work for other scripts but fail for this particular one (sharepoint_to_json.py)?
How can I fix the missing file error in my Docker setup?
Is there a better way to verify if the ODBC driver is correctly installed and recognized within the container?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

If you docker run -it --rm python:3.12 cat /etc/os-release you'll see that the python:3.12 image is based on Debian 12 Bookworm, so you should not be pulling packages from Debian 10 repositories.

What's the output of cat /etc/odbcinst.ini when run inside your container? The current version of msodbcsql17 installs /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.6.1, so it's unclear why you have things looking for libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1.
